# drawLayer:inContext not displaying drawing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, xcode8, draw

I'm trying to draw a blue circle inside a *UIView* subclass on Xcode 8, Swift 3. Inside a Cocoa Touch file that I'm using as the class for a *View* object in the *Storyboard*, I wrote the following code, but the circle is not displayed:

```
import UIKit

class testView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        ctx.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
    }
}
```

This version with `UIKit` doesn't display the circle neither:

```
override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
    let p = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    p.fill()
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on your question and this are my results, first of all you need to get you CurrentGraphicsContent, if you don't do this, you can't draw anything, so try with this code

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        ctx.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        ctx.fillPath()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    // Drawing code
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Reiner! Your implementation with Core Graphics works. I found out too that draw(layer:inContext) didn't work because it has to be implemented on a CALayer subclass